# Devise custom controller Missing Template create

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-confirmable

I have two different Devise Models on my rails app: Studios and Musicians.

I'm trying to get everything work with my custom controllers, because Musicians "has_one" adress and some other stuff. My Musicians model has the following Devise methods

```
:database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
:confirmable, :lockable
```

And at **devise.rb** I have:

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days
```

But my main problem is with the method "after_inactive_sign_up_path_for", it seens that its never being called at all. After create I get the following:

```
ActionView::Missing template (missing template musicians/registrations/create,
musicians/registrations/create, devise/registrations/create, devise/create,
application/create   with --bunch of options and places where he did the search--)
```

But as far I studied Devise views I don`t need a create view (never needed actually)...
By the way, it creates the active record, sends the email and all the stuff, the problem is just the last part :(

Here is the important part of **routes.rb**

```
devise_for :musicians, :controllers => {:registrations => 'musicians/registrations'}
#Here is the route that I want to redirect the user, it works, already tested
match 'logado', to: 'sessions#logado',  via: [:get, :post]
```

Here is my **controllers/musicians/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Musicians::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    @musician = Musician.new
    @adress = @musician.build_adress
    @asset = @musician.build_asset
  end

  def create
    @musician = Musician.new(params[:musician])
    @adress = @musician.build_endereco(params[:musician][:adress_attributes])
    @asset = @musician.build_asset(:photo => params[:musician][:asset])
    if @musician.save
      flash[:sucess] = "Welcome"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  protected
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    logado_path
  end
end
```

My views are organized like this:

```
views
|--musicians
   |--registrations
      new.html.erb
      edit.html.erb
      _form.html.erb
   |--sessions
      new.html.erb
      _form.html.erb
 index.html.erb
```

I'm on Rails 4, Ruby 2 and latest Devise version, guess it is 3.2.2 - Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

```
....
if @musician.save
  flash[:sucess] = "Welcome" #<- i think problem here 
else
....
```

after `save` you need redirect to some path or render something

something like this

....

```
if @musician.save
  flash[:sucess] = "Welcome" #<- here
  return redirect_to some_path #<- path to redirect
else
```